# Why does H2 balk at line continuation '\' in stored procedures?

Tags: database, h2

(1) Try creating an inline stored procedure with end of line continuation marks.  Here is the NEXT_PRIME example from the user manual with end of line continuation marks added:

```
DROP ALIAS IF EXISTS NEXT_PRIME;
CREATE ALIAS NEXT_PRIME AS $$ \
    String nextPrime(String value) { \
        return new BigInteger(value).nextProbablePrime().toString(); \
    } \
$$;
```

(2) Observe the errors:

Syntax error in SQL statement "/org/h2/dynamic/NEXT_PRIME.java:7: illegal character: \92
    public static  \
                   ^
...etc

There is a good reason why I ask this question.  If line continuation was correctly supported within thee '$$' block, it would be feasible to keep/maintain multi-line stored procedures with normal multiline SQL statements in an ordinary java string property resource file.  Yes, what I wrote here implies that an ordinary SQL statement in H2 allows line continuations just fine. eg:

```
//stringid=\
create table if not exists test(\
     id int,\
     name varchar,\
);
```

The above SQL create statement including the string id "//stringid" can be cut and pasted from the java property file listing directly into the H2 console and will execute without errors!

Answer (score 1):

Java and SQL databases don't require or allow line continuation characters. If you need them for some reason, remove them before executing the statement.

Answer (score -1):

Thomas, your answer is a good one for Java but not so good when compared to the inline translation unit properties of any other SQL stored procedure implementation.  Obviously one would not put continuation characters in a Java compilation unit but since '\' followed by '\n' continuation is allowed in SQL it should be allowed for inline H2 Java within $$ blocks.  [Presumably the continuation marks would be filtered out before submitting the inline code to the Java compiler.]

Is it not the goal of H2 to be competitive with other common SQL implentations?  If so, why break the SQL notion of translation unit for stored procedures?  Stored procedure syntax varies in each implementation but every implementation treats stored procedure code as SQL.

Comment: Actually, `\\` isn't allowed in any SQL database I tested, except for H2. This might be a bug (I will check).